# Symfony 4 BadCredentialsException return 500

Tags: php, rest, symfony

when I try : 
`throw new BadCredentialsException('invalid token')`

I obtain in prod or dev a `500`error page, not a 401/403

How I can do that ?

In my `AuthTokenAuthenticator` class as service to catch header with x-token

Comment: Are you using the namespace? 
`use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;` in top of your php script.
More, what does the error log says?

Comment: yes, and the stacktrace is not very interesting. juste generate 500 not 400 (i tried to specified to)

Comment: I use this model https://zestedesavoir.com/tutoriels/1280/creez-une-api-rest-avec-symfony-3/ without fos et jms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw an exception that implements *HttpExceptionInterface*.

For example

```
throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException();
```